# Normalization in the $O(n)$ model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, spin-chains

The $O(n)$ model is the model of $n$-dimensional spins $\vec{s}_i$ at each lattice $i$ which are restricted to be on the $n-1$ dimensional sphere of radius $S$ with Hamiltionian
$$H(\vec{s}_1,\dots,\vec{s}_N)=\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}\vec{s}_i\cdot\vec{s}_j.$$ Usually $S$ is taken to be $\sqrt{n}$. Is there some physical reasoning behind this? In [McGreevy's notes](https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/f18/2018F-217-lectures.pdf) this is important to relate the $O(n\rightarrow 0)$ model to self-avoiding walks. I did some thorough note on this found [here](https://github.com/ivanmbur/Maestria/blob/master/Statistical%20Field%20Theory/The%20O(n-_0)%20Model%20and%20SAWs.pdf). It is also used in the [treatment of Stanley](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789814365802_0001) on the $O(n\rightarrow\infty)$ model.